# Force download html to pdf using php

Tags: php, pdf

I try to make force download html-file to pdf and use the code below

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\''. basename($file) .'\'.pdf');
header("Content-type: application/pdf");

echo file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/index-1.html');

?>
```

I get some file with `.pdf` extention but when I try to open it, i get an error `not PDF or corrupted'. What's wrong and how to make it work?

Comment: open that downloaded "pdf" file with a texteditor like notepad and check if the page didn't actually return an error instead of the PDF you were expecting.

Comment: Also, are you trying to put raw HTML into a pdf file and expect it to work? Or are you really downloading a valid pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

Telling the browser that some data is a PDF will not magically transform the data into a PDF.

You'll need to do that yourself, e.g. using the PHP [PDF library](http://php.net/pdf) or [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put html in a pet file and expect it to work you need to use something like dompdf to convert html to a pdf file: https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

For even better results and support for floats I would use the following library. I got extremely good results with it. The reason why this one is working so well is because they use the WebKit browser rendering engine to render the html before converting it to pdf giving you almost 1 on 1 results when comparing it to the browser.
https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a properly PDF file. You can do this using some PHP classes like [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default) or [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).